# elementwise operations on a multindex column failing due to join or level confusion

Tags: python, pandas

I have a three-level multindex column   `Name, Period, Measurement`  In my toy example, I have weight and height for two time periods 'before' and 'after' for three different people.

I want to generate a dataframe that shows the `weight` divided by `height` for each of the three names during the `before` period.

I am making some kind of error in my use of `level=` parameter I suspect (or perhaps .  But no matter what i try, I get a `TypeError: Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous`

I would like to understand how to control operation so that i could specify, "show me, by name, where period='before', the weight divided by height"  and also the more general, "show me, by name, and by period, the weight divided by height"

```
arrays = [['mike', 'mike', 'mike', 'mike','matt', 'matt', 'matt', 'matt','dave','dave', 'dave','dave', ], 
          ['before', 'before', 'after', 'after']*3, 
         ['height', 'weight']*6]
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('name', 'period', 'statistic'), )
the_data = [[1.8, 200, 1.7,170]*3,[1.8, 190, 1.7,166]*3 ]
idx = pd.IndexSlice
xf = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start="20191201", periods=2, freq="d"),
                         data=the_data, columns=cols)
xf.loc[:, idx[:,'before','weight']].divide(xf.loc[:, idx[:,'before','height']], level=[0], axis='columns')
```

Comment: A bit random, why I get this message: `NameError: name 'idx' is not defined`

Comment: @SathishSanjeevi sorry, forgot the definition. `idx = pd.IndexSlice`  i added it back to the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For correct alignment is necessary same MultiIndex values, so you can use `rename` here:

```
print (xf.loc[:, idx[:,'before','weight']]
          .divide(xf.loc[:, idx[:,'before','height']].rename(columns={'height':'weight'})))
name              mike        matt        dave
period          before      before      before
statistic       weight      weight      weight
2019-12-01  111.111111  111.111111  111.111111
2019-12-02  105.555556  105.555556  105.555556
```

If want append output to original `DataFrame`:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df = (xf.loc[:, idx[:,'before','weight']].rename(columns={'weight':'new'})
           .divide(xf.loc[:, idx[:,'before','height']].rename(columns={'height':'new'})))

xf = pd.concat([xf, df], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (xf)
name         dave                                    matt                \
period      after        before                     after        before   
statistic  height weight height         new weight height weight height   
2019-12-01    1.7    170    1.8  111.111111    200    1.7    170    1.8   
2019-12-02    1.7    166    1.8  105.555556    190    1.7    166    1.8   

name                            mike                                   
period                         after        before                     
statistic          new weight height weight height         new weight  
2019-12-01  111.111111    200    1.7    170    1.8  111.111111    200  
2019-12-02  105.555556    190    1.7    166    1.8  105.555556    190
```

If possible, you can use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), so solution is simplify:

```
df1 = xf.xs(('before','weight'), axis=1, level=[1,2])
df2 = xf.xs(('before','height'), axis=1, level=[1,2])

print (df1.div(df2))
name              mike        matt        dave
2019-12-01  111.111111  111.111111  111.111111
2019-12-02  105.555556  105.555556  105.555556
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Just missed `values` during division:

```
print(xf.loc[:, idx[:,'before','weight']].divide(xf.loc[:, idx[:,'before','height']].values, level=[0], axis='columns'))
```

results in:

```
name              mike        matt        dave
period          before      before      before
statistic       weight      weight      weight
2019-12-01  111.111111  111.111111  111.111111
2019-12-02  105.555556  105.555556  105.555556
```